# Meteor-Up Deployment Failure on Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: meteor

I am having failures with deploying a meteor project to my server. I am using mup and it fails consistently. I have tried to follow all the instructions I found online with no success.

```
    Tonys-MacBook-Pro:.deployment tonyj$ mup deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments

“ Checkout Kadira!
It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Building Started: ../

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'app' (linux)
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Uploading bundle
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setting up Environment Variables
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Setting up Environment Variables: SUCCESS
[xx.xx.xx.xx] - Invoking deployment process
[xx.xx.xx.xx] x Invoking deployment process: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-47-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.5 install: `node ./build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.5 install script 'node ./build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/app/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/app/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Do `mup setup` before you do `mup deploy`

if you have done that, try to doublecheck node version you have used for development, and which one mup is trying to install on server. It might be that you need to specify another one in `mup.json` try `"nodeVersion": "0.10.40"` for example.

Comment: I ran mup setup with no issues and I've tried changing the nodeVersion to the appropriate build version. I also tried increasing the deployment time to over 100 seconds. It still failed.

Comment: Similar issue was reported there https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/714 ,  try to change node version to 10.40 and then re run mup setup after that again. If that is how you did it, then I am not sure what else to do

Comment: I did that (changed the node version to 10.40), ran setup and deploy again but it still failed. Although, the errors look a little different

Answer (score 0):

I used mupx (developmental version of mup) as against mup and I was able to upload my project without any hassle.